# Rlink : loading an option a package from the R side

Tags: rlink

Perhaps a stupid question but I need to ask it.

According to the blog of Matt Asher, the following code permit a perfect sample simulation

```
    perfectSample = 
        RFunction["perfect.sample <- function(n, myDist, params = c()) {
          x <- seq(0,1,length=(n+2))[2:(n+1)]

          if(length(params)) {
         toEval <- paste(c(\"sapply(x,q\", myDist, \",\", \
       paste(params,collapse=\",\"), \")\"), collapse=\"\")
       } else {
       toEval <- paste(c(\"sapply(x,q\", myDist, paste(params,collapse=\
       \",\"), \")\"), collapse=\"\")
       } 

         eval(parse(text=toEval))
       }"];
```

gives a perfect sample simulation. It works nicely on poisson distribution

```
     perfectSample[100, "laplace", 10]
```

but for a laplace distribution I need library(VGAM) to be loaded on the R side. How could I do that ?

Comment: `REvaluate["library(VGAM)"]`?  This assumes you have that library installed.  Unless you're on Windows, installing libraries requires using an external R installation, not the ancient R 2.14 that comes with RLink ...